# How to deploy LoopBack 4 application in vercel or other host?

Tags: deployment, vercel, loopback, loopback4

I maked one simple project using loopback 4, but deploy didn't work in vercel. How can I make it work???

[Deploy](https://stock-server-eosin.vercel.app/)

OBS: The visual setup its work, but the routes and explorer not.

[Visual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leR5O.png)

[Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlGDo.png)

Comment: i am also trying to deploy loopback 4 on vercel. I didnt make it ti even homepage just as you did. Can you share your vercel config file and guide how are you doing it ?

Comment: I would like to know also